# >>Project management

Tags: java, backup, project, logging

I usually code by myself but currently I need to do a java web-based project with 8 of my friends. I would like to ask the following questions:

1) How to **document the development** properly? Like how to keep a daily log? Any software or format suggested? What things do you think are important to be included in the log?

2) How to **code together**? Is there any software/IDE that allows a team to code together? Something ike google docs?

3) How to do a proper **backup for a team project**? Any software or tips to share?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is several questions at once and some of them belong to programmers SE site instead. This is a Q&A site, try to break up the questions.

Comment: The title says it all, I do not think any of this is a programming question.

Comment: and I am sure we already have answers for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Collaborative coding: its not the IDE that you can thank for collaborative coding, its all in distributed source control... like git or mercurial. Svn is also good for source control but is less good for collab.

Backup: git and mercurial solve this problem.

Documenting the project's progress is best suited in a task manager / project manager of some kind. I use projo project manager.. mostly because I wrote it. There's other well known apps out there like basecamp, and competitors.